# JFreeChart Bar Charts - Draw plot without gradient fill

Tags: colors, jfreechart, gradient, fill

My Bar chart is always drawn with a gradient fill. I have a code to fill each bar in a series with a different color. I just want the colors without any effect. I looked at a previous thread but that did not help since it seems to be designed for a default standard code.

Here is my code:

```
CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);

CategoryItemRenderer renderer = new MyRenderer();
plot.setRenderer(renderer);

class MyRenderer extends BarRenderer 
{ 
 private Paint[] barColors;
 public MyRenderer() 
 { 
    this.barColors = new Paint[] { new Color( 21, 104, 156),  new Color( 25, 149, 104), new Color( 237, 179,20), 
      new Color( 72, 181, 163) }; 
 }
 public Paint getItemPaint(final int row, final int column) 
 { 
    // returns color for each column 
    return (this.barColors[column % this.barColors.length]); 
 } 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the `BarRenderer` class you will find this method:

```
public static void setDefaultBarPainter(BarPainter painter);
```

It allows you to change the default bar painter (pass a `StandardBarPainter` to this method before creating any charts and your charts will have bars without the gradient).